# Implementing own realloc

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to change the size of array when it exceed its limit. I have created a function for that.

```
void AddElemenet( int i , int value){

   if( i > index - 1){
    int tmp = index;
    double *new_arr;
    while( i > tmp){
       tmp*=2
    }
    new_arr = new double[tmp]();
    for( int j = 0; j < index ; j++){
       new_arr[j] = arr[j];
    }
    index = tmp;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = new_arr;
    }
    arr[i] = value;

}
```

index refers to the max size of an array ; and arr is dynamicly allocated array using `new` itself.
The problem is , that i am assigning arr to a local variable that get destroyed. I tried assignign it as refference or pointer using `*arr=*new_arr`

but nothing worked so far. How can i change the array using this local variable?

Comment: is `arr` an array? or a pointer?

Comment: its dynamicly allocated array using new . i will add it to the question info.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this (besides using `new` and `delete` in C++, that's a different issue). `arr` points to the newly allocated array (that `new_arr` points to).

Comment: Please don't re-type code - copy and paste the original code - there's no point working with an approximation of the real code.

Comment: then doing `arr = new_arr` should be fine. you're coping the local pointer, not what its pointing to so you don't have any issues with `new_arr` going away

Comment: Why on earth are you not just using `std::vector`?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what isn't working?

Comment: If i add element , on index that is higher than allocated size , it wont get added to it. The condition result in true and all , but when i print the array afterwards it just still prints value of the original array.

Comment: Where is `arr` defined?

Comment: btw, there are 2 `i`s in your code. please change one

Comment: oh didnt notice that , fixed it. Still wrong output tho.

Comment: Don't fix this code. Throw it all away and start using `std::vector`.

Comment: Unfortunately , i want to use this in another code , which needs to have overloaded [] and it throws seg fault with vectors.

Comment: Than fix the segafult with vectors, bug is in your code, not the code of vector.

Comment: my guess is `new_arr` is getting destroyed when going out of scope, try `new_arr = nullptr` at the end of your function. Let us know if that works

Comment: Also, on a different note, you're adding an INT into an array of DOUBLE, not sure why

Comment: Array's size is fixed. Just use std::vector as its malleable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various bugs in your implementation demonstrate why it is almost always a good idea to use the standard library. It would be very simple to adapt `std::vector` to this interface.

The essence of your problem is the confusion over what `index` means. (That's a terrible name for a member variable. It says nothing. Index of what? And actually, it's not an index; it's the size of the array. At least, that's what it should be.)

Suppose that your array has 4 elements, so `index` is 4 (based on the assumption that it is the size of the array). Now you want to `AddElement(4, 42);`. The condition in `if( i > index - 1)` is certainly true: `i` is 4, and `index - 1` is 3. So the reallocation block will be entered. However, the first thing you do is `tmp = index; while( i > tmp) tmp *= 2;`. `i` is not greater than `tmp` -- both of them are `4` -- so the loop will never run and `tmp` will still be `4`. Now you allocate a new array with four elements, copy the existing four elements to it, "update" `index` to 4 (its current value), and delete the old array. Right afterwards, you attempt to set the element with index 4 to 42. But the array only has four elements, so that is Undefined Behaviour.

Since you have not actually changed the size of the array, or the value of `index` which indicates its size, your later attempt to print the values of the array will stop at its actual size, ignoring the value you modified outside the storage area of the array (which may belong to some other datastructure, so its value is meaningless anyway.)

If you rename `index` as `size` and `tmp` as `new_size`, the code is much clearer, and the fix is also clear:

```
if (i >= size) {
  size_t new_size = size;
  while (i >= new_size) new_size *= 2; /* NOT > */
  double* new_array = new double[new_size]();
  for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j) new_array[j] = array[j];
  array = new_array;
  size = new_size;
}
array[i] = value;
```

---

This would all have been much simpler and less error-prone if you used a `std::vector`:

```
class MyVector {
  public:
    void AddElement(size_t i, double value) {
      if (i >= data_.size()) data_.resize(i + 1);
      data_[i] = value;
    }
    /* Many implementation details omitted */
  private:
    std::vector<double> data_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector <int> list;    

void AddElemenet(int value)
{
    list.push_back (value);     
}
```

Just use vector's. Array's size is fixed. Vector's size is dynamic.